# WPF Only Require Assembly References When Dependent Functions Used

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dependencies

I have a created a WPF assembly that offers a set of attached behaviors (attached properties with property changed code) that can affect a wide range of third party controls.

Example:

- TreeViewBehavior: Requires reference to Windows.Controls
- RadTreeViewBehavior: Requires reference to
  Telerik.Windows.Controls.Navigation

Some of my users will never use the RadTreeViewBehavior, but they still have to have a reference to Telerik.Windows.Controls.Navigation in their project.

How can I made it so that my users will only need to add references to assemblies that they are actually using?

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, your assembly is dependent on Telerik.Windows.Controls.Navigation and without it your assembly is incomplete. You will either need to remove any use of that assembly in yours, or try merging/embedding the assemblies using something like IlMerge or SmartAssembly.

I would recommend splitting the assembly into one that has behaviours for System.Windows.Controls and one that has behaviours for Telerik.Windows.Controls.Navigation